# XML Schema validation with empty namespace

Tags: java, xml, xsd, schema

I tried to understand follow all the (complicated) rules of XML Schema handling, but still I cannot figure this out!
My problem is this:

- I have an XSD;
- I want to create and validate XML files based on this XSD, *without* a prefix on elements;
- I want editors like jEdit, Eclipse, etc. to handle auto-completion based on XSD.

However, all validating editors give me the same error message.

Here is a stripped-down version of the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.megadix.org/standards/temp.xsd" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jfcm="http://www.megadix.org/standards/temp.xsd"
elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xsd:complexType name="MapsType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="map" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"></xsd:attribute>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="concepts" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="concept" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"></xsd:attribute>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="maps" type="jfcm:MapsType"></xsd:element>
```

If I use a prefix, files correctly validate and auto-complete:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jfcm:maps xmlns:jfcm="http://www.megadix.org/standards/temp.xsd">
<map name="Test Map">
    <concepts>
        <concept name="c1" />
        <concept name="c2" />
        <concept name="c3" />
    </concepts>
</map>
```

But if I remove it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<maps xmlns:jfcm="http://www.megadix.org/standards/temp.xsd">
<map name="Test Map">
    <concepts>
        <concept name="c1" />
        <concept name="c2" />
        <concept name="c3" />
    </concepts>
</map>
```

I get this error message:

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'map'. One of '{map}' is expected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using "unqualified" for element's form, this is the correct way of doing it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<maps xmlns="http://www.megadix.org/standards/temp.xsd">
  <map name="Test Map" xmlns="">
    <concepts>
      <concept name="c1" />
      <concept name="c2" />
      <concept name="c3" />
    </concepts>
  </map>
</maps>
```

If you want all elements to "share" on the namespace, you have to define elementFormDefault="qualified"; as a sidebar, many XSD designers would consider this as a good advice.

Comment: I'm not sure the given xml is valid. Because your target namespace should refer to the one of the specific namespaces defined for context.

Comment: @Phani, I can assure you that it is, based on the XSD (well, I had to move the attribute after the sequence, but that's irrelevant to our issue here). One thing you have to remember is that a document element (or root) must have the target namespace of the XSD; all other nested within, as long as they're locally defined (as the author did) may not; elementFormDefault controls that; in this case, would be unqualified.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand lot about namespaces and their relationship in terms of validation from here.

[XML Schema Validation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ccl.soa.sdo.xsd.ui.tutorial.doc/topics/xml_schema_lesson13.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that prefixes are irrelevant. It's the namespace that counts.

If you want the "maps" element to be in no namespace, then you must declare it that way in the schema. Currently you have declared it as a global element declaration in a schema document with a target namespace.

Your requirement seems very strange. Your instance document declares a namespace, but then it doesn't use that namespace for any of the elements in the document. That's legal, but it's a very odd thing to want to do.